# Doctrine expr()->isNull causes 500 internal server error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, isnull

I've been stumped over this issue for 2days.
I have a PHP doctrine code as follows

```
$qb->andWhere(
$qb->expr()->andX(
    $qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->eq('wr.isApproved', ':approved'),

        //The code below break (500 internal server error occures)
        $qb->expr()->isNull('wr.isApproved')

    ),
    $qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->eq('wr.isVerified', ':verified'),
        $qb->expr()->isNull('wr.isVerified')
    ),
    $qb->expr()->isNull('wr.isPaid')
)
);
$params['verified'] = true;
$params['approved'] = false;
```

Note, $qb is an instance of a repository class

The code above breaks with 500 internal server error at line 6.
I've tried the following
-Getting the actual SQL statement generated and ran against the DB (It worked).
-Commenting all other code and leaving just line 6 (Code breaks)

-I'm using Doctrine version :2.7.1
_PHP version : 7.4

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Which exact error is being reported?